# Android O auto location suggest feature (aka autofill), how to turn off

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

As we have our App on Android O, there's a new feature introduced there, where it auto-suggest Home and Work location as per image below.

[image]

What is this called? Is there a way to disable it from our Edit Text showing it?

Comment: Can you share your XML code for EditText?. Maybe try something like `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` on `EditText`

Comment: `textNoSuggestion` is already in used. But the autofill feature is ignoring it. Perhaps should be a bug file to Google. Anyway, I found a way to programmatically control it as per my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Filed an issue to google on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66975175

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently in Android-Oreo, there's this new feature call AUTOFILL

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html, where `By default, the view uses the IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_AUTO mode, which lets Android use its heuristics to determine if the view is important for autofill`

Hence for field that is not intended to have that filled, just add the below to your view.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setImportantForAutofill(IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO);
    }
```

**Update**: Found another approach to disable AUTOFILL
Use `android:importantForAutofill="no"` in the XML
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/testautofill.html#trigger_autofill_in_your_app

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is not a solution, it doesn't work for all cases, to Disable the Autofill completely on a particular View you should extend it and override getAutofillType() method:

```
class TextInputEditTextNoAutofill : TextInputEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun getAutofillType(): Int {
        return View.AUTOFILL_TYPE_NONE
    }
}
```

This is Kotlin version, but you can get the point. Showcase repo: 
https://github.com/BukT0p/AutofillBug